# how to handle FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: ActivityManager and java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]

Tags: android

I have a device (samsung galaxy fit). When I turn on the device I can't go to the Homescreen and it just keeps loading. When i connect the device and see the logcat, my logcat error showed -

```
"FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: ActivityManager and java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]"
```

How to handle it?

Comment: Place some logs first.... memory issues can happen because of many ways like due to bitmaps sizes,not unregistering receivers etc. so attach some logs so that it will be easy for us....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some way to solve out of memory error

first recycling the bitmap like this

```
bmp.recycle();
bmp = null;
```

second using the garbage collector

```
System.runFinalization();
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
System.gc();
```

but it'll be better if you post some of your code here so I and the other people can help you more :)

Comment: honestly, i dont know what happen with my device. how i can follow your advice if i can't go to homescreen? in my logcat i find "Device doesn't have enough space to save dump file (under 15MB)". sorry im panic :(

Comment: as I say,can you post your code here?when the error occured?and about you can't go to homescreen try to restart your device and if the error still occured, factory reset (be careful this will erased your data)

Comment: finally i did factory reset my device. now my device back to normal. thanks ;)

Comment: After factory reset my device and connected it to my logcat again, my logcat dont showed anything

Answer (score 0):

using following code you have to check OutOfMemory Error

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    try 
    {
        // We need to recyle unused bitmaps
         if (Main_bitmap != null) 
         {
                    Main_bitmap.recycle();
         }

      Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
      String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
      Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
      {
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);


                        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                      bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
                      BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,bmpFactoryOptions);

         if ( checkBitmapFitsInMemory(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth,bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight, 2)) 
        {
                            BitmapFactory.Options options4 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            options4.inSampleSize = 1;
                            Main_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options4);
                        iv_set_image.setImageBitmap(Main_bitmap);

        }
        else
        {

             Toast.makeText(this,"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:", 1).show();             

         }
                    cursor.close();
     } 
     catch (Exception e)
    {
             e.printStackTrace();
     }
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}    



    public static boolean checkBitmapFitsInMemory(long bmpwidth,long bmpheight, int bmpdensity )
    {
        long reqsize=bmpwidth*bmpheight*bmpdensity;
        long allocNativeHeap = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize();


        final long heapPad=(long) Math.max(4*1024*1024,Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()*0.1);
        if ((reqsize + allocNativeHeap + heapPad) >= Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: how to running this code?? im so confused because i cant go to home screen