# Android: out of memory error when using bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

i often get out of memory errors in my app. I believe it has to do with the bitmaps i download  from the server. Any ideas why?

```
**A method in my activity that sets up ListView:**

private class NewsFeedArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AnimalLocationLog> {

    ArrayList<AnimalLocationLog> objects;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> urls;
    ImageDownloader downloader;     

    public NewsFeedArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<AnimalLocationLog> objects, ArrayList<String> urls) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
        this.urls = urls;
        downloader = new ImageDownloader();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, parent, false);

        AnimalLocationLog current = objects.get(position);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView firstline = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstline);
        TextView secondline = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondline);

        // Download external images
        downloader.download(urls.get(position % 14), image);

        firstline.setText(current.getSpecies());
        secondline.setText("Spotted " + current.getDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd H:m"));

        return rowView;
    }


**ImageDownloader.java:**

    public class ImageDownloader {

        Map<String,Bitmap> imageCache;

        public ImageDownloader(){
            imageCache = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

        }

        //download function
        public void download(String url, ImageView imageView) {
             if (cancelPotentialDownload(url, imageView)) {

                 //Caching code right here
                 String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
                 File f = new File(getCacheDirectory(imageView.getContext()), filename);

                  // Is the bitmap in our memory cache?
                 Bitmap bitmap = null;

                  bitmap = (Bitmap)imageCache.get(f.getPath());

                  if(bitmap == null){

                      bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());

                      if(bitmap != null){
                          imageCache.put(f.getPath(), bitmap);
                      }

                  }
                  //No? download it
                  if(bitmap == null){
                      BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
                      DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = new DownloadedDrawable(task);
                      imageView.setImageDrawable(downloadedDrawable);
                      task.execute(url);
                  }else{
                      //Yes? set the image
                      imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                  }
             }
        }

        //cancel a download (internal only)
        private static boolean cancelPotentialDownload(String url, ImageView imageView) {
            BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);

            if (bitmapDownloaderTask != null) {
                String bitmapUrl = bitmapDownloaderTask.url;
                if ((bitmapUrl == null) || (!bitmapUrl.equals(url))) {
                    bitmapDownloaderTask.cancel(true);
                } else {
                    // The same URL is already being downloaded.
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        //gets an existing download if one exists for the imageview
        private static BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
            if (imageView != null) {
                Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
                if (drawable instanceof DownloadedDrawable) {
                    DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = (DownloadedDrawable)drawable;
                    return downloadedDrawable.getBitmapDownloaderTask();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        //our caching functions
        // Find the dir to save cached images
        private static File getCacheDirectory(Context context){
            String sdState = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            File cacheDir;

            if (sdState.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                File sdDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  

                //TODO : Change your diretcory here
                cacheDir = new File(sdDir,"data/tac/imagess");
            }
            else
                cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();

            if(!cacheDir.exists())
                cacheDir.mkdirs();
                return cacheDir;
        }

        private void writeFile(Bitmap bmp, File f) {
              FileOutputStream out = null;

              try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(f);
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, out);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
              finally { 
                try { if (out != null ) out.close(); }
                catch(Exception ex) {} 
              }
        }
        ///////////////////////

        //download asynctask
        public class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            private String url;
            private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

            public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
                imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
            }

            @Override
            // Actual download method, run in the task thread
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                 // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
                 url = (String)params[0];
                 return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
            }

            @Override
            // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    bitmap = null;
                }

                if (imageViewReference != null) {
                    ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                    BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
                    // Change bitmap only if this process is still associated with it
                    if (this == bitmapDownloaderTask) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        //cache the image


                        String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
                        File f = new File(getCacheDirectory(imageView.getContext()), filename);

                        imageCache.put(f.getPath(), bitmap);

                        writeFile(bitmap, f);
                    }
                }
            }


        }

        static class DownloadedDrawable extends ColorDrawable {
            private final WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask> bitmapDownloaderTaskReference;

            public DownloadedDrawable(BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask) {
                super(Color.BLACK);
                bitmapDownloaderTaskReference =
                    new WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask>(bitmapDownloaderTask);
            }

            public BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask() {
                return bitmapDownloaderTaskReference.get();
            }
        }

        //the actual download code
        static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
            final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
                final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
                    Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url); 
                    return null;
                }

                final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    try {
                        inputStream = entity.getContent(); 
                        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        return bitmap;
                    } finally {
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            inputStream.close();  
                        }
                        entity.consumeContent();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or IllegalStateException
                getRequest.abort();
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url + e.toString());
            } finally {
                if (client != null) {
                    //client.close();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use [these guidelines](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). If that doesn't help, search stackoverflow for your question. There're lots of questions about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have high resolution image , you should scale them down. See the topic under Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory.
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
[Out of memory error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620843/out-of-memory-error-android)

On how to avoid them:
[How to avoid an out of memory error while using bitmaps in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151719/how-to-avoid-out-of-memory-error-while-using-bitmap-in-android)

For an oveview:
http://blogs.innovationm.com/android-out-of-memory-error-causes-solution-and-best-practices/
http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html