# how to get all image link location from url diractory

Tags: android, image, android-internet

i have uploaded some images on cloud storage in a directory / folder.

example: `http://dropbox.com/image-directory/`

now my question is how can i get link location of all the images that is stored in URL directory / folder and store these links to an array.

please visit this url: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5be3kgehyg8uzh2/AAA-jYcy_21nLBwnZQ3TBFAea
this is the URL of directory that contains images

Comment: You want links or images?

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077177/outofmemoryexception-load-bunch-of-images-from-server

Comment: instead of adding every image link location manually i want to get all image link location and add them automatically

Comment: He just want to give a directory URL which ultimately contains URL of images. Using that directory URL, he wants load all the images.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use JSoup for Parsing HTML in to android programming .

You need to search it By img tag. But `1 Limitation` it will give all the element content like the single drop box image.

You can Try your URL [Here](http://try.jsoup.org/). Also Download Library of it from  [Here](http://jsoup.org/download).